# Sorting items category wise with one element without category

Tags: php, sorting

I have list of categories in this order:

```
1.base
2.cat1
3.cat2
4.cat2
5.base
6.cat3
7.cat2
8.cat1
9.base
```

I want it to be sorted it category wise except the base which can be displayed as single just after or before other category, but not in group. Like this:

```
1.base
2.cat1
3.cat1
4.cat2
5.cat2
6.cat2
7.base
8.cat3
9.base
```

Comment: Could we see your existing code, so we know how we can improve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
//store final result
    $res=array();
//categories displayed
    $done=array();
//array to be sorted
    $type= array('Base','cat1','cat1','cat2','Base','cat2','cat1','cat2','Base');


         for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($type);$i++) { 
            $c='';
            $c=$type[$i];           
            if ($c=='Base' && !is_exist($c,$done)) {
                $res[]=  $type[$i];
                $done[]= $type[$i];


            }
            elseif($c!='Base' && !is_exist($c,$done)) {
                $done[]=$c;

                for ($j=0; $j <sizeof($type) ; $j++) 
                {   
                    if ($type[$j]==$c) {
                        $res[]=$type[$j];
                    }


             }  

                }


             }

   //print the result.       
    print_r($res);


    function is_exist($x,$done){
        $found=false;
        if (!empty($done)) {

        for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($done) ; $i++) { 
            if ($done[$i]==$x) {
                $found=true;
            }
        }

        return $found;
    }

    }

    ?>
```